# Vertical lines appear in Chrome when moving a div across (and on top) SVG

Tags: google-chrome, svg, qtip2, visual-artifacts

I am using a qTip2 div as a tooltip when hovering over an SVG element. In Chrome, white vertical lines appear over the SVG (to the left of my qTip div) whenever I move the mouse and the tooltip follows it. They disappear only when the tooltip disappear.

Why does this happen, and is this fixable?